# Building a pure P2P networking system?

Tags: authentication, networking, p2p

Is it possible to build a purely P2P based network with no centralized servers and a way to privately authenticate network updates?

I'm not asking for a way to code this, as I am not yet able to code something like this, I just want to know if it is possible, and what the best way to go around it would be.

Here's some examples of what I mean:

P1 somehow connects to all other peers, and discovers P2.

P2 has a more updated version of the network data, so P1 downloads it, and discovers a new node added to the network; P3.

P3 wants to push a new network update. P3 has a way to authenticate his new update, and uses it to send a new update to the network, P1 and P2.

P2 recieves the update, and sees it is authenticated. Meanwhile, P2 has a more updated version of the network, and pushes it on to P1 and P4, using another way to confirm the update is authenticated.

Checking if other peers network data is up to date could be done via hashing the data and exchanging them.

My problem at the moment is I am unsure if it is possible to connect to a P2P network without a central host (like in bittorrent), and the authentication system.

I only want peers with the authentication key (or whatever I would be using) to push network updates, and for the recievers to push them on, without having the key to send new updates.
The authentication key should not be able to be snatched by network sniffers or retrieved in any other way by clients without the key.

Is this possible, and if so, what concept should I use?
It should be impossible to reverse engineer or decompile to retrieve a way to push unauthenticated updates.

Comment: I just created an answer on viable p2p technologies and using [Dat Project](https://datproject.org) in a decentralized video app on mobile: [A: p2p video/audio chat on android using WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45476871/8295283)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called the internet :)

What you are describing is basically a routing protocol. You might want to take a look at RIP and OSPF, I know that both of those support authentication but I have not used the authentication myself. You can also take a look at STP (a bridging protocol), but I don't think it has authentication.

Most of the internet was designed to be peer-to-peer. As a military technology, any single node could potentialy be destroyed, so having a single central server would be a weakness. This philosophy lives on today, although we are more worried about a power failure than a nuclear attack.